# Twitter OAuth: How do we log the user out of twitter?

Tags: php, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth, logout

I am using the oauth method in order to allow a user to sign into my website with Twitter and Facebook. I also plan to add Yahoo! and Google as well such as Stack Overflow does. Once the user logs in with Twitter successfully they have the option of logging out.

I want to make it to where when the 'Log out' button or link is selected, the user is logged out of my site AND TWITTER. I need it to log out of Twitter also in the case that the user is accessing my website and not Twitters. How do I do this?

Demo and example at: [develop.f12media.com](http://develop.f12media.com)
The user clicks on 'Login' at the top of the page to log in with their Twitter account.

Answer (score 8):

Redirecting the user to http://twitter.com/logout will probably work.

But don't do it. OAuth isn't meant to behave that way. Just log the user out of YOUR site.

Logging in to your site via OAuth doesn't necessarily log them in at Twitter, so logging *out* via your site shouldn't log them out either.

Comment: Logging into my site via Oauth is logging the user into Twitter also.

Comment: I was able to redirect the user to http://twitter.com/logout so the user could logout of twitter also.

Comment: @Kevin, accessing an OAuth token from twitter does NOT necessarily log the user into Twitter. It might, but that's really up to Twitter. Stay out of it.

Comment: Even if logging into your site doesn't necessarily log the user into Twitter, that doesn't mean that allowing the user to log _out_ of twitter is something that should never be done. Actually, there are cases where you need to ask the user to log out of Twitter whether or not he logged in at all into your site, (oh sh* the stupid comment length limit, I'll continue in the next comment)

Comment: actually you may need that _especially_ if the user is not logged in your site and you have no access token. Consider for example when the user visits your site for the first time and is using a friend's computer so he is already logged in but not with the user he wants to be logged in (he doen't even know). So you want to give him the possibility to log out and

Comment: in again with a different user.

Answer (score 1):

In Facebook it can be done easily because facebook provides logout.php and it takes `next=sendBackURL` as param.

so when user clicks on Logout button of your application, we can just invoke above logout URL, which will log out the user and smart facebook URL `next=sendBackURL`  will send to your application login page.

But the above seems difficult in twitter,  but I think if I do the same, then user will be on Twitter site but he will be logged out of both ur application and twitter.

so it can be by sending `authorize?force_login=true`,  it will be called or will get redirection just after your application logs out user from your site, and user will be directed to Twitter again, I have tested it logs out user from twitter, although it will ask twitter credentials again, but no issue, user can just ignore that.

If Twitter can also provide some logout url, which takes next URL, it will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not the user is authenticated on the Twitter site is between the user and the Twitter site. You don't have access or control to that. You only have control over your auth token for that user on your site. You could expire the user's auth token when they log out of your site, but that only affects their Twitter authentication through your site. All that would accomplish is making it so they have to authenticate with Twitter again the next time they log into your site.

I think you're trying to accomplish something you don't need to here. This is the expected flow of OAuth and you shouldn't be worrying about logging the person out of a 3rd party site.

Comment: When the user logs in to my website, they are redirected to twitter to login to my website using twitter. I found that it DOES log the user into twitter.

Comment: I didn't say that it wouldn't, in fact I would expect it to when you are requesting the token from Twitter. The issue still is that you shouldn't worry about whether the user is logged into the Twitter site. 

Aside from the obvious, do you even know that your users want to log out of Twitter when they log out of your site? What if I'm using Twitter and your site at the same time and I log out of your site?

Comment: On that note, even if you know for a fact that your user wants to log out of Twitter, it's still a bad idea. It's hacky and disrupts the expected flow.

Comment: The issue is information security. Lets say a user signs into my site with twitter, then logs off my site. If another user sits down and goes to twitter, the last user will still be logged in.

Comment: @Kevin, In my opinion you're better off informing your users of that risk. There is no technological solution that guarantees you can log them off of Twitter from your site.